# Pip installed packages don't show up in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

Many Python packages don't have pre-built `conda` packages, so Anaconda users are frequently forced to use `pip` to install packages.  I have to do this routinely, since so many packages don't have conda packages, not even in the most common alternate channel(s) like `conda-forge` or `bio-conda`.

This open issue was already reported in the Anaconda github support repo https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10634.  However, no answers have been forthcoming in almost 1 year.  I am asking here because responses are typically faster and shared more widely than in support forums for individual products.

I hate the productivity loss of re-installing Anaconda, particularly a long-standing installation, because it can take 3-4 hours to backup and export existing environment build files as `requirements.txt`, remove an existing Anaconda installation, clean out the Windows Registry, search the Windows file system for leftover detritus, and then rebuild all of my environments one at a time.

Does anyone know a trick, or have a Python script or some other workaround(s) to refresh the Package Index within a conda environment or for ALL environments created and managed by the Anaconda Navigator GUI.  It would be awesome if there was an updater widget within the Anaconda Navigator GUI to allow users to select for which virtual environment(s) they want the package index to be updated.

### What I have tried

In the Anaconda Navigator GUI "Environments" tab, clicking on the "Update Index..." button does not get updated with the list of packages installed "behind the scenes" from a Anaconda Command Prompt.

### The result I get

pip-installed packages are NOT included in the Anaconda Package Index update process.  It does not find packages in environments installed inside and outside of the Anaconda3 root directory.  It doesn't even find all packages underneath the `\envs` folder.  This makes me think packages are not installed into the currently selected environments, so it takes time to verify their location in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs, C:\Users\username\AppData\Local, or elsewhere.

What else I have tried: after having a corrupted Anaconda and Spyder installation that would not start at all, I posted requests for help on various support forums.  I got answers that were not much help, like "Just don't mix `pip` and `conda` packages, use one or the other".  That is not practical since so many Python packages are not available in the conda package format.  I have gotten that impractical advice from Anaconda and Spyder developers in the past.

### Severity and impact

This is an important issue, since it is possible to use / misuse conda and pip and inadvertently corrupt Anaconda so badly that it requires a painful and time-consuming removal and re-installation of the entire Anaconda distribution.

A possible solution beyond my current cable-tow... If someone can build an intelligent and transparent converter built into the PyPi, Anaconda Cloud, Conda-forge, and other channels that made this conversion automatic and validated, then this conversation might not be needed.

Comment: This article seems like it might be relevant: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/. _Many Python packages don't have pre-built conda packages, so Anaconda users are frequently forced to use pip to install packages. I have to do this routinely, since so many packages don't have conda packages, not even in the most common alternate channel(s) like conda-forge or bio-conda._ ... _That is not practical since so many Python packages are not available in the conda package format._ Can you give some examples of popular ones?

Comment: Also, it seems like there are multiple distinct issues/questions in here, it might be worth organizing them further.

Comment: @AMC Thanks for your response.  It addresses some issues, with guidance to avoid corrupting conda envs.  Too many packages exist in pip format without conda equivalents; and this problem happens every time pip packages are updated without conda versions.  The article you linked here essentially says "treat conda envs like they are sterile. Add only conda packages to keep the env clean. But after you pip it, no more conda or you risk corruption.  Once pip has been used, conda will be unaware of the changes.  The conda index won't reflect pip's changes."  Don't interleave conda and pip.

Comment: The `Best Practices Checklist` https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/ is very useful.  1) use conda first, and as long as possible. 2) then use pip, knowing that you can/should never go back.  3) conda environments keep things smaller and more manageable.  4) don't pip your 'root' environment; if you think you must, build the conda package yourself (if possible). 5) don't pip with the –user argument, avoid all “users” installs. 

Once pip has been used conda will be unaware of the changes.  
Store conda and pip requirements in text files to keep a record of your changes.

Comment: @AMC Thanks for the article.  The article is very relevant.  For me this corruption problem is an urgent issue (not just important).  I have environments to build this week, and many have no pip packages.  Now I know that I must create a package inventory in advance, then build the core with conda, and then dead end my environment development by layering in the pip packages last.  This requires me to plan better (and see into the future?).  I also must inventory frequently (output and save requirements.txt and environment.yml files).  If time permits, I will split this into distinct issues.

Comment: I don't know if you've seen this yet: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html.

Comment: Thank you. Here's how it works. ```conda config --set pip_interop_enabled True```  "With this interoperability, conda can use pip-installed packages to satisfy dependencies, cleanly remove pip-installed software, and replace them with conda packages when appropriate.  This feature is still experimental and is therefore off by default."   This helps because it provides a way to replace pip-installed packages with their conda equivalent (if the conda equivalent exists).  To salvage a conda-built environment, this could be done after every pip installation in a pristine conda-built environment.

Comment: You should compile all these explanatory comments into an answer!

Comment: There's no simple answer forthcoming.  My additional comments are only a set of observations and recommended practices.  The current conda 4.6.0 release is still a hack; it does not eliminate the problem.  We still cannot mix and match conda and pip installations and updates without eventually creating a fubar'd installation of Anaconda that requires total removal and re-installation.

Comment: Can you share some examples of PyPi packages that you need which are missing from Conda? I've been wanting to learn more about Conda and the packaging process.